# How Can I Output Only the First Word of the Title of an Entry in a Template?

Tags: templating, titles

Is it possible to output only the first word of the title of an entry in a template? If so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with Twig alone. Here's how:

```
{{ entry.title|split(' ')|slice(0, 1)|join }}
```

This series of Twig filters:

1. Uses `split` to turn the title into an array, splitting on spaces.
2. Passes that array through `slice` to grab the first item in the array.
3. Then uses `join` to turn the array back into a string for output. The array is now just one item (the first word of the title), but `join` is needed because Twig doesn't want to treat an array as a string.

Answer (score 5):

There is also a nice plugin called [Hacksaw](https://github.com/ehousestudio/craft_hacksaw/) that gives you a handful of helpers. With this you can do `{{ entry.title|hack(words='1') }}`